# Wget like utility to download all images in mysite.com/img/ directory

Tags: command-line, bash, wget

My access to the mysite.com/img/ directory is blocked.

However all the images in that directory are in the form `n.jpg` where n is the nth image.

My access to `mysite.com/img/n.jpg` is not blocked

Is there anyway I save images 1-500 (`mysite.com/img/1.jpg` to `mysite.com/img/500.jpg`)?

I'm using ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest solution is probably to use bash brace expansions

```
wget http://mysite.com/img/{1..500}.jpg
```

There is also the option of doing a loop, allowing you to put a bit of wait between each requests.

```
for n in $(seq 1 500); do
  wget http://mysite.com/img/${n}.jpg
  sleep 0.1
done
```

(The above can be ran directly in the shell.)

Comment: Not related, but is this loop appliable to any other similar command that we want to work with {n} files?

Comment: Yes, that is a very generic loop, which can be run together with any commands. See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/loops1.html for some more examples.

Comment: Thanks, it was really useful to simplify some of my scripts.

Answer (score 1):

There is also another way to do this with `wget` that I have used successfully for one site, and you should be able to modify the instructions below for other sites. It involves generating a list of urls and then feeding that list to `wget`.

1) As an example lets say you want to download all 63 pdf magazines of [Full Circle Magazine](http://fullcirclemagazine.org/) (an Ubuntu magazine), but your download manager cannot download them all at once. So find the [link](http://dl.fullcirclemagazine.org/issue1_en.pdf) of the first pdf file and quickly check that the other magazine links are in the same url format.

2) With the knowledge gained in part 1, we can now turn to our script to generate the urls. The script below runs an until loop, which I have modified (credit to its originator). You modify this script by placing the number of magazines in the `until [ $i = 63 ]` part and place the correct url after `echo` and make sure the `"$i"` is in the correct part of the url to be echoed so that it changes with every run of the loop. The urls are generated and then appended to a text file- this happens in a split second when the script is run and is not as complicated to set up as it sounds!

Save the script in a text editor, make it executable and run it; modify it as described above when you want to download from a *different* site than my example.

```
#!/bin/bash
   i=0
   until [ $i = 63 ] ; do
    i=$(($i+1))
    echo "http://dl.fullcirclemagazine.org/issue"$i"_en.pdf" >> url.txt
done
```

3) Finally, assuming that `url.txt` is in the current working directory, run:

```
wget -i url.txt
```

If you want to save the downloads elsewhere add `-P ~/MyDirectory` after `url.txt`

It does work- if you try it, enter `ctrl c` to abort if you don't want to download them all!