# How to download specific images from a site index with wget?

Tags: command-line, downloads, wget, find

Let's suppose that I have access to a site index and in a specific directory of this index I have a lot of images, but some of those images were resized (the originals are still there). The resized images have their own name, following this standard: `[image-name][-resolution].jpg`, and the original images have their name following this standard: `[image-name].jpg`.

- So, I'd like to know how to download all the original images, using `wget`?

**Note**: There is no space in the image names, and I specified that the file type is `.jpg`,  because I don't know if there is any difference in downloading this type of file.

Comment: Maybe duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17604/wget-recursive-for-only-files-that-pass-a-regexp

Comment: @Aurelien Questions are only considered as 'possible duplicates' if they are actually on Ask Ubuntu itself.

Comment: You probably want to look at the answers [in this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/115817/wget-like-utility-to-download-all-images-in-mysite-com-img-directory).

Answer (score 2):

wget [supports regexes](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html%5fnode/Types-of-Files.html) with the `--accept-regex` parameter.

So `wget -A "1024x768.jpg"` would download any file ending with "1024x768.jpg". If you want different sorts of resolutions the digits can be changed to match `d+`. Something like:

```
wget -A "d+xd+.jpg$"
```

(pseudo example). The regex depends on the shell you use.